# cannot instantiate abstract class while creating CTI adaptor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, com, atl

i am trying to Build a CTI Connector Solution in Visual Studio 2008 using CTI Toolkit 4.03. i got an error

```
Error    1    error C2259: 'ATL::CComObject<Base>' : cannot instantiate abstract class    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h    1801   while compiling
```

my code is

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "MyAdapterBase.h" 

STDMETHODIMP CMyAdapterBase::GetAdapterName(BSTR* bsName)
{ 
  bsName = SysAllocString(L"My Sample CTI Adapter"); 
  return S_OK;
} 
STDMETHODIMP CMyAdapterBase::GetAdapterVersion(BSTR bsName)
{ 
  bsName = SysAllocString(L"1.0 Candidate 2"); 
  return S_OK; 
} 
STDMETHODIMP CMyAdapterBase::UIAction(BSTR message){ 
{ 
  return S_OK; 
} 
void CMyAdapterBase::SendUIRefreshEvent(_bstr_t xml) 
{ 
  CCTILogger::Log(LOGLEVEL_HIGH,"Sending XML (len %d): %s",xml.length(),
    (wchar_t)xml); 
  _ISalesforceCTIAdapterEvents_UIRefresh(xml); 
}
```

Comment: You should show us the problematic code... the more information you provide, the more helpful answer you'll get.

Comment: The problem is because you have some method in COM interface that is not implemented in your COM class. You'd better post the interface definition and the COM class definition.

Comment: The posted code snippet is irrelevant. Post full error log, and note it should take you more precisely to your source code problematic position further on the fragment you cut away. My guess is you are trying to use a static or stack-allocated instance of COM class, whereas you are supposed to create using `CComObject<...>::CreateInstace`

Answer (score 0):

that's because you can't make an instance of an abstract class, it has to be a concrete one. You could write your own class which inherits from the CComObject class or use an existing implemented class, besides it's hard to help without any source

Comment: i change a bit in my code n i got some different errors now . cod is as follows:

Comment: my code is
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyAdapterBase.h"
STDMETHODIMP CMyAdapterBase::GetAdapterName(BSTR* bsName){
  *bsName = SysAllocString(L"My Sample CTI Adapter");
  return S_OK;}
STDMETHODIMP CMyAdapterBase::GetAdapterVersion(BSTR* bsName){
 *bsName = SysAllocString(L"1.0 Candidate 2");  return S_OK;
 }
STDMETHODIMP CMyAdapterBase::UIAction(BSTR message){
{  
return S_OK;
}
void CMyAdapterBase::SendUIRefreshEvent(_bstr_t xml)
{
CCTILogger::Log(LOGLEVEL_HIGH,"Sending XML (len %d): %s",xml.length(),(wchar_t*)xml);
_ISalesforceCTIAdapterEvents_UIRefresh(xml);
 }

Comment: could you please give it properly formatted in your original question?